# Debian 12 screen resolution

Tags: linux, debian, graphics-card, hdmi

Before I start to ask for a help. I am windows user, Linux for me is complicated.

I bought a new graphics card the Radeon RX7000 series for my computer. On iGPU everything is okay, but dGPU screen resolution is default 720p and cannot change.

I run a command while using iGPU - "find /sys -name edid":

`/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1/edid` `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-2/edid`

When I run same command while with dGPU the output is empty. I did install radeon drivers.

Please, if someone could assist me with this issue. Thanks